# having trouble with mysql UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a submit button on the page submitting and it comes back blank and does not update , the echo is also blank.

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $newtext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
        $doTextEdit = "UPDATE `$database_main`.`texts` SET `texts`.`text` = '$newtext' WHERE `texts`.`id` = '$sid' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());

        $retval = mysql_query( $doArtistEdit, $main );
        if(! $retval )
        {
            die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
    ?>
```

This is in the form code

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="$ID" method="post">
        Song Name : <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row_song['title']; ?>"> by Artist Name :<input type="text" name="artist" value="<?php echo $row_artist['artist']; ?>"><br><?php echo $sid; ?><?php echo $database_main; ?><?php echo $doTextEdit; ?>
        Lyrics :<br><textarea name="text" cols="72" rows="20"><?php echo str_replace("\n","\n",$row_Recordset1['text']); ?></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="editlyrics" value="Edit"></form>
```

Comment: Where does the variable `$sid` get set?

Comment: Do not use the submit button to check whether a form has been submitted. This is due to an IE bug that does not send the button when the user uses the keyboard to submit. It only sends when the button is clicked using the mouse.

Comment: yeppers i'm clicking it and in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if `$_POST['submit']` is set -

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

But your submit button name is `editlyrics`, so it should be -

```
if (isset($_POST['editlyrics']))
```

Add a hidden input inside your form -

```
<input type="hidden" name="song_id" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
```

And now your code would be something like-

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['editlyrics'])) {
    $song_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song_id']);
    $newtext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
    $doTextEdit = "UPDATE `$database_main`.`texts` SET `texts`.`text` = '$newtext' WHERE `texts`.`id` = '$song_id' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());

    $retval = mysql_query( $doTextEdit, $main );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
?>
```

Note that you should not be writing code using the outdated `mysql_` functions, and learn either `mysqli` or `PDO` - [php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: UPDATE `mydb`.`texts` SET `texts`.`text` = 'i love cokz\r\nuck my sockzzz\'zzz\'zg gvgvgv' WHERE `texts`.`id` = '' LIMIT 1  Lyrics :
that got it, but the id isnt being passed.
sorry for the noice question, but i need to pass the form name i to the ID feild


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="<?php echo $sid; ?>" method="post">

Comment: You can pass the ID back in a hidden input field and then get it out of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: like this? first time dealing with hidden form feilds passing into var's 
<input type="hidden" name="songid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">

$id = $_GET['songid'];

$doTextEdit = "UPDATE `$database_main`.`texts` SET `texts`.`text` = '$newtext' WHERE `texts`.`id` = '$id' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up a SQL query in `$doTextEdit` but you are passing `$doArtistEdit` to the `mysql_query()` function.

Comment: changed it still not updating... weird i dont see the solution